# Methods and optional parameters

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have read in the Apple Documentation that we can use optional parameters in objective c methods call. Example from the Apple documentation :

> Methods that take a variable number of parameters are also possible,
>   though they’re somewhat rare. Extra parameters are separated by commas
>   after the end of the method name. (Unlike colons, the commas are not
>   considered part of the name.) In the following example, the imaginary
>   makeGroup: method is passed one required parameter (group) and three
>   parameters that are optional:

```
[receiver makeGroup:group, memberOne, memberTwo, memberThree];
```

Can someone tell when to use this feature and how ? is there any example in the Apple API ?

thanks

Comment: héhé. I am tired. arrayWihObjects is a good axample.

Comment: [Cocoa with Love: Variable argument lists in Cocoa](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html)

Comment: Whenever you use NSLog you use the feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of method you are describing is called a *variadic* method.  Examples in Cocoa include `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` and `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]`.  You access the arguments of a variadic method (or function) using the macros defined in `stdarg.h`.

Here's an example of how the `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` method might be implemented:

```
+ (NSArray *)arrayWithObjects:(id)firstObject, ... {
    int count = 0;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, firstObject);
    id object = firstObject;
    while (object) {
        ++count;
        object = va_arg(ap, id);
    }
    va_end(ap);

    id objects[count];
    va_start(ap, firstObject);
    object = firstObject;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        objects[i] = object;
        object = va_arg(ap, id);
    }
    va_end(ap);

    return [self arrayWithObjects:objects count:count];
}
```

Comment: Much better answer than mine. (up voted). I couldn't track down the specifics. It's not in the docs, and if you don't know what header file to look at, you're out of luck.

Comment: Note that variadic arguments to methods should be used quite sparingly.  The compiler can't properly type check the arguments.   In general, it is best to have very specific argumentation (though, certainly, variadic arguments can be quite useful).

Answer (score 0):

I've written a method like that once or twice. It's a bit of a pain. It works very much like  parsing a command line in a C program.

I don't remember now where I found the documentation on how to do it. If I remember correctly, it uses functions va_start() and va_end().

A major down-side of that approach is that the comma-delimited list of parameters are not type checked, and don't have labels like they do in normal methods.

The main way it makes sense to use that approach is in a method like NSArray's arrayWithObjects, where you need to allow a variable-sized list of parameters of any type, or NSLog.